# For some reason not displayed at home... It may be something better than I know, but I'm here days... Ionic 4

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4

I was making my code for a job, an application, and when I wanted to add some Modal but it went wrong so as I can't clean and remove Modal codes, I deleted everything and did it again. Doing it again, I redo the same process but for some reason the home page doesn't look like the home page. I know maybe it's a really stupid mistake but take it easy please I'm a simple studen... xD

I say here my code, to ask me to help, say thank you!

https://github.com/JosmarStrech/Sport-Tool

Comment: It'd be best to narrow down you code to what you think the issue is and post it here.

Comment: Also if you wish to share code then share like this: https://github.com/gokujy/ioniccanvas.github.io  remove node module, plugins, and platform folder and upload other things,

Comment: You can use ionic predesigned tabs template for this. Just hit this command to create "ionic start myApp tabs" and then after you can add more tabs and homepage into it.